# Difficult to debug dom selectors in chai-webdriver

Tags: webdriver, mocha.js, chai

I'm having trouble figuring out if chai-webdriver is even working. In the following example

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var chaiWebdriver = require('chai-webdriver');

describe('TWT Plugin', function () {
  var capabilities, driver;
  before(function (done) {
    capabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.set("chromeOptions", {
      "excludeSwitches": ["ignore-certificate-errors"]
    });
    driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities).build();
    chai.use(chaiWebdriver(driver));
    return done();
  });

  after(function (done) {
    return driver.quit().then(done);
  });

  it('should be embeddable', function () {
    driver.get('http://localhost:3000/page.html');
    expect("h1").dom.to.contain("text");
  });
});
```

when I run `mocha test/integration/test_plugin.js --timeout 15000` I get `AssertionError: expected 'h1' to include 'text'` but I don't get any message explaining what was contained in the selector, so I'm having a hard time even knowing if it matched anything. Any suggestions on how to debug or otherwise improve this?